# toggle body background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I hope someone can help me with this, I have this javascript code that toggles my body background

```
function changeDivImage() {
    imgPath = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
    if (imgPath == "url(images/bg.jpg)" || imgPath == "") {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/bg_2.jpg)";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/bg.jpg)";
    }
}
```

I activate it with this link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeDivImage()">change</a>
```

my problem is that it works fine in IE and firefox, but in chrome, the links work twice then stop working, it basically switches to bg_2.jpg then once clicked again switches back to bg.jpg then it never works again :/

also, is there an easier way to accomplish this? css only maybe? basically i have two body background pictures and i want to be able to click on the link to toggle 1, then click again to toggle 2 instead, then back to 1, etc...

lastly, how can i make the two backgrounds fade in and out? instead of just switch between the two?

Comment: Side note: It should be `var imgPath` in your code except if you have already defined it somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS classes!

**CSS Rules**

```
body { background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); }
body.on { background-image: url(images/bg_2.jpg); }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function changeDivImage() {
    $("body").toggleClass("on");
}
```

If you want to fade, you will end up having to fade the entire page. Use can use jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Comment: this is great, gave me so many awesome ideas, unfortunately no IE support :(

Comment: i added css transition: background .4s ease-in-out; and that gave me the fade-in/out effect for the background only ;)

Comment: got this to work in IE, instead of assigning the background images to the body, i added a wrap div with width 100% and height 100% and applied that to it! works like a charm :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution:
(This also supports additional images).

```
var m = 0, imgs = ["images/bg.jpg", "images/bg_2.jpg"];

function changeDivImage()
{
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgs[m] + ")";
    m = (m + 1) % imgs.length;
}
```

Here is the **[working code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvEtq/)**.

Here is the **[jQuery version on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VdAV/)**.

**UPDATE: *CROSS-FADING Version***

Here is the **[cross-fading jQuery version on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftdmw/)**.

You wouldn't want the whole page (with all elements) to fade in/out. Only the bg should fade. So, this version has a div to be used as the **background container**. Its **z-depth** is arranged so that it will keep itself the bottom-most element on the page; and switch between its two children to create the cross-fade effect.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="bg-top"></div>
    <div id="bg-bottom"></div>
</div>
<a id="bg-changer" href="#">change</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#bg, div#bg-top, div#bg-bottom
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 500px;*/ /* height is set by javascript on every window resize */
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#bg 
{
    z-index: -99;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
var m = 0, 
/* Array of background images. You can add more to it. */
imgs = ["images/bg.jpg", "images/bg_2.jpg"];

/* Toggles the background images with cross-fade effect. */
function changeDivImage()
{
    setBgHeight();
    var imgTop = imgs[m];
    m = (m + 1) % imgs.length;
    var imgBottom = imgs[m];
    $('div#bg')
        .children('#bg-top').show()
        .css('background-image', 'url(' + imgTop + ')')
        .fadeOut('slow')
        .end()
        .children('#bg-bottom').hide()
        .css('background-image', 'url(' + imgBottom + ')')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}

/* Sets the background div height to (fit the) window height. */
function setBgHeight()
{
    var h = $(window).height();
    $('div#bg').height(h).children().height(h);
}

/* DOM ready event handler. */
$(document).ready(function(event)
{
    $('a#bg-changer').click(function(event) { changeDivImage(); });
    changeDivImage(); //fade in the first image when the DOM is ready.
});

/* Window resize event handler. */
$(window).resize(function(event)
{
    setBgHeight(); //set the background height everytime.
});
```

This could be improved more but it should give you an idea.

Comment: anyway I an use this with fading the pictures in and out?

Comment: Yes, added cross-fading jQuery version to the post.

Comment: thank you very much, im trying to to work this out, will report right back

Answer (score 1):

There's a cleaner way to do this. As a demo, see:

```
<button id="toggle" type="button">Toggle Background Color</button>

var togglebg = (function(){
    var bgs = ['black','blue','red','green'];

    return function(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgs[0];
        bgs.push(bgs.shift());
    }
})();

document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = togglebg;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KYDKG/

Obviously, you would replace the `Color` with `Image`, but all this does is iterate through a list that's local to the `togglebg` function, always using the first available. This would also need to run `window.onload`, preferably as a `window.addEventListener`/`window.attachEvent` on the `button` or elements that will trigger it to run.

Or with jQuery (as I notice the tag now):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var togglebg = (function () {
        var bgs = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green'];

        return function () {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgs[0];
            bgs.push(bgs.shift());
        }
    })();

    $('#toggle').on('click', togglebg);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KYDKG/1/

And here is a [DummyImage version](http://dummyimage.com/) using real images:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var togglebg = (function () {
        var bgs = [
                '000/ffffff&text=Black and White',
                '0000ff/ffffff&text=Blue and White',
                'ffff00/000&text=Yellow and Black',
                'ff0000/00ff00&text=Red and Green'
            ],
            url = "url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/{img}')";

        return function () {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = url.replace('{img}', bgs[0]);
            bgs.push(bgs.shift());
        }
    })();

    $('#toggle').on('click', togglebg);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KYDKG/2/